# How to get value from a column in different sheet if condition met? (refer explanation below)

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheet which is Record & Main.

Record is the list of user record inserted to system. I need to check whether the rate in Record sheet correct or not by comparing the rate in Main sheet.

I want excel to return the Rate based on user Document Date.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

[Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5wm9.png)

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DWgD.png)

Comment: You can probably use `SUMIFS` for this.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman im sorry, but im really not sure how to do it. I cannot do it by lookup. Appreciate your suggestion sir.

Comment: Assumnig Record is a worksheet and Main is a worksheet and your data starts in cell A1 in each, then try per @BigBen's suggestion: =SUMIFS(Main!$D:$D,Main!$A:$A,Record!A2,Main!$B:$B,"<="&Record!B2,Main!$C:$C,">="&Record!B2)

Comment: @TechnoDabbler, please don't answer questions in comments. As it says in the comment placeholder text. "Avoid answering questions in comments." There's a reason for that.

Comment: @TechnoDabbler thanks for your help. i already verified the result. Really appreciate it. Maybe you can put it in answer. So i can mark it as completed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Record is a worksheet and Main is a worksheet and your data starts in cell A1 in each, then try per @BigBen's suggestion:

```
=SUMIFS(Main!$D:$D,Main!$A:$A,Record!A2,Main!$B:$B,"<="&Record!B2,Main!$C:$C,">="&Record!B2)
```

Cheers :)